# How can I make background image of the same div change while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I need to change the background image of the div while it is scrolling
like in this [site](http://landor.com/)

Comment: apply a scroll event and get the offset top position and change the background image accordingly. **post code and get help** this is the way you could get better answers. even the code which you tried and not worked will do. good luck!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this simple html layout:

```
<div class="background x1"></div>
<div class="background x2"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

and this css:

```
body, html, div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  height:1500px;
}
.x1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ETDz5z46Loo/maxresdefault.jpg);
}
.x2 {
  background-image: url(http://www.neyralaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/tokyo-blue-background-4547.jpg);
}
.background {
  background-size:cover;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;  
}
```

You have 2 background images in your web covering always the full window, one on top of another.

The `content`is the container of your future project, I just give it 1500px height so a scroll bar will show.

Then, with just this easy jquery:

```
var change = $('.x2');
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var op = $(this).scrollTop();
  change.css({
    'opacity': (1 - op / 100)
  });
});
```

you will make the `x2` image to gradually change it's opacity from 1 at no scroll to 0 at 100px scroll.

This is imo better than to make the image change at a fixed scroll point even if you add a transition to make it fluid.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/wSkmL/849/)**

```js
var change = $('.x2');
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var op = $(this).scrollTop();
  change.css({
    'opacity': (1 - op / 100)
  });
});
```

```css
body, html, div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  height:1500px;
}
.x1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ETDz5z46Loo/maxresdefault.jpg);
}
.x2 {
  background-image: url(http://www.neyralaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/tokyo-blue-background-4547.jpg);
}
.background {
  background-size:cover;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background x1"></div>
<div class="background x2"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

> EDITED: second aproach

A more simple way with transition and chaning the images at a fixed scroll position could be using this script:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $(".x4").addClass("opacity");
      } else {
        $(".x4").removeClass("opacity");
      }
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $(".x3").addClass("opacity");
      } else {
        $(".x3").removeClass("opacity");
      }
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
        $(".x2").addClass("opacity");
      } else {
        $(".x2").removeClass("opacity");
      }
  });
```

where you add a class when scroll a 200, 400 and 600px to your image containers:

```
.opacity {
  opacity: 0
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/wSkmL/850/)**

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $(".x4").addClass("opacity");
      } else {
        $(".x4").removeClass("opacity");
      }
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $(".x3").addClass("opacity");
      } else {
        $(".x3").removeClass("opacity");
      }
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
        $(".x2").addClass("opacity");
      } else {
        $(".x2").removeClass("opacity");
      }
  });
```

```css
body,
html,
div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 1500px;
}

.x1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ETDz5z46Loo/maxresdefault.jpg);
}

.x2 {
  background-image: url(http://www.neyralaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/tokyo-blue-background-4547.jpg);
}

.x3 {
  background-image: url(http://awalls.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/free-backgrounds-for-desktop-2BE.jpg);
}

.x4 {
  background-image: url(http://fewfice.com/dcim/llp/22/4363196-hd-background.jpg);
}

.background {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  opacity:1;
}

.opacity {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background x1"></div>
<div class="background x2"></div>
<div class="background x3"></div>
<div class="background x4"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: how can i add more than two images

Answer (score 0):

Okay! As you have not posted any code, i would suggest you some steps to get to it:

1. Bind a scroll event.
2. Then get the offset top position.
3. Now according to the offset top position you can change the background.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code. You can add if or switch statement to add needed class

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
  var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollAmount > 200) {
$('.main-bg').addClass('jason-bg');
  }
// or you can do with switch statement instead of IF

});
```